# Simplest way to see that the Euler density is topological

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, gauss-bonnet

I’m looking for a simple way to see that the integrated Euler density $\sqrt{g} \, E_{2n}$ is topological (i.e. metric-independent in general even dimension $2n$). I can see it it must be true in two dimensions since $E_2 = R$ and because of the two-dimensional relation between the Ricci and scalar curvature $R_{\mu\nu} = (R/2)g_{\mu\nu}$ which implies that the variation vanishes
\begin{equation}
\delta \int \mathrm{d}^{2}x \sqrt{g} \, E_2 = \int \mathrm{d}^{2}x \sqrt{g} \left(R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}R g_{\mu\nu}\right) \delta g^{\mu\nu} = 0
\end{equation}
I suspect that the key to general dimension lies in the formula
\begin{equation}
E_{2n} = \frac{1}{2^n} {R^{i_1j_i}}_{k_1l_1} \cdots {R^{i_nj_n}}_{k_nl_n} \epsilon_{i_1 j_1 \cdots i_n j_n} \epsilon^{k_1l_1\cdots k_n l_n}
\end{equation}
but it’s unclear how to proceed other than brute force.

Comment: Look at [Anderson: The variational bicomplex][1], page 129, Example 4.14.


  [1]: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/AndersonVariationalBicomplex.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BenceRacskó. That’s interesting. I now think you can also see it by direct computation using dimensional-dependent identities from https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/dimensionally-dependent-identities/132CC39ACF23D53920F7475893F9C033 If I have time I’ll try to write an answer based on this later